# How to get rid of an extra middle part my permalink

Tags: permalinks

On my newly created site the permalinks look like this: mysite.com/wordpress/xyz(editable permalinks)

I can't seem to be able to edit the 'wordpress' part, i.e it is treated as part of the URL(?).  naturally, I don't want it there, so what can I do, how can I get rid of it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you installed WordPress in a directory (called `wordpress`).

You can update your Site Url and do some modifications to fix that. The Codex has a detailed article on how to proceed - https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install